# Why am I unable to install package into a venv while it works using conda in the same machine?

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-venv

I have created a venv which I call `PyRepo` from a Miniconda installation locally. So far it has been working well as I was able to install third party packages from my `venv` using `pip install <PackageName>` no problems. However, I bumped into this one package `blpapi` that will install from conda (in the same machine):

```
(base) C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64>pip install blpapi
Looking in indexes: https://nexus-tp.xxx.net/repository/public-pypi/simple
Requirement already satisfied: blpapi in c:\programs\miniconda3_64\lib\site-packages (3.14.0)
```

but when I attempt to do the same from the `PyRepo` venv then it produces the following error:

```
(PyRepo) c:\Xxx\Dev\PyRepo>pip install blpapi
Looking in indexes: https://nexus-tp.xxx.net/repository/public-pypi/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blpapi
```

I have tried many different ways but they all fail with the same error:

```
pip install --user blpapi
python3 -m pip install blpapi
python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade blpapi=3.14.0
pip install --isolated blpapi
```

I'm quite puzzled as what goes with this `blpapi` package as all other packages install fine in my venv. Also note that the installation on the conda environment uses the same nexus repository and it works while it doesn't in the venv. How can I fix this? are there any workarounds? e.g. copying the installation from the local conda to my venv `PyRepo`? How to manually copy the installation from conda to my venv safely or trigger a transfer install?

Comment: Looks like you will have to refresh yout pipy "repo" try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Maybe the package has been removed from pypi and not from conda

Comment: Have you tried:  `python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi` as described here: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/

Comment: @cel thank you! good hint, the corporate firewall blocks this. Besides, it is hosted in our corporate nexus and conda install succeeds even the pip install from conda works, the issue is when installing it on my venv in the same machine.

Comment: Well then it seems the firewall is the main issue here :-). Depending on your restrictions you may be able to download the appropriate file from https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple/blpapi/, transfer it manually and then pip install the file.

Comment: Sorry, just read it again. I doubt that the pip install from the conda environment works. It just sees that the package is already installed (via the conda index) and then tells you that nothing needs to be done. `blpapi` is simply not in the pypi index, so if your corporate index doesn't contain this third-party package (which it doesn't seem to do) then you won't be able to get via a pip install.

Comment: _I bumped into this one package blpapi that will install from conda_ That shows you installing it using pip, though. Did you copy/paste the wrong thing?