# How to transfer a library installation from a conda environment to a venv that uses pip?

Tags: python, pip, conda

As the title says I need to transfer an installation from conda to a venv that uses pip instead. Is there a way to transfer the installation? either automatically or manually?

More background into my actual use case can be found here:
[Why am I unable to install package into a venv while it works using conda in the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587542/why-am-i-unable-to-install-package-into-a-venv-while-it-works-using-conda-in-the)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what `transfer` means here. If it's the same python interpreter and a pure python package, then chances are good that copying the folder in `lib/pythonx.y/site-packages` from one environment into the other will work. Note that this is more a hack than a good solution and i would not recommend doing that unless you are sure that there's no better way to solve your original problem.

Comment: I have done this but pip won't see it. When I do `pip list` it will not show the blpapi package.

Comment: Why are you mixing conda and other virtual environemtn tools? Why not create a conda env?

Comment: I'm not mixing them, that's the main purpose of my separated venv to have an isolated environment and dependencies for a given project. Do you mean I should create a conda virtual environment instead of a venv virtual environment? The decision was driven by the choice of tools i.e. PyScaffold which we use is integrated with pip and not with conda AFAIK.

Comment: Instead of "transferring", have you tried recreating? That is, first do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from the activated Conda env, followed by  `pip install -r requirements.txt` from your new (non-Conda) environment. It will reinstall everything fresh, but that's likely safer and more reliable than trying to copy Conda builds of packages to non-Conda envs (e.g., I expect any Cython-compiled stuff will be lost or break since Conda uses `@rpath` linking).

Comment: @merv thank you for your comment and help! yes I tried this before of course but due to corporate restrictions etc I have no access to installing it via pip install since the blpapi library isn't in the pypi index. Furthermore, raising the issue in IT support takes a long time :D